# YAML to JSON Puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm a new to Puppet and looking to create a JSON file and get content from YAML. Any help is appreciated.

cred.yaml

```
---
user:pass
```

cred.json

```
{
    "username": "user",
    "password": "pass"
}
```

Comment: More context is needed here.  Among other things, is the YAML file on the client or on the server?  Are you looking to make this transformation on a per-run basis, or just once?

Comment: If you're looking to drop some facts on a node and have Puppet do something with them when it compiles the catalog then I think both would work, maybe take a look at this https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.5/external_facts.html.